# I want to count a same letter if the previous letter is the same as the current letter

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace

I have the input string `"lorrem ipsssum dollorrrrum"` and I want to count the same letter **if** the **current** letter is the same as the **previous** letter and change all the **next** same letter to the counted that letter,

**I want the exact result to look like this:**

```
"lor2emips3umdol2or4um"
```

I am stuck and I don't know what algorithm should I use, and what keyword to search about this issue in Google :(

**The code I've written so far**

```js
function countLetter(str) {
    return str
        .replace(/\s/g, '')
        .split('')
        .reduce((a, b) => {
            return a === b ? b.replace(b, '') : b;
        });
}

window.onload = function () {
  console.log(countLetter('lorrem ipsssum dollorrrrum'));
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a regular expression, you can capture a character and then backreference that same character 1 or more times. Use a replacer function to replace the matched section with the character and the number of characters in the full match:

```js
function countLetter(str) {
    return str
        .replace(/\s/g, '')
        .replace(/(\w)\1+/g, (match, char) => char + match.length);
}

console.log(countLetter('lorrem ipsssum dollorrrrum'));
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, you saved my day but hey, is there anything other than regex? I mean Regex is too complex for a beginner like me.

Comment: The pattern `(\w)\1+` is super simple, you shouldn't be afraid of using it. `\w` - Match a character `\1+` - Repeat that captured character 1 or more times. There are alternatives, sure, but I think this is the clearest, most concise way by far

Answer (score 3):

With an alternation and a capture group, you might also use a single replacement.

Using a ternary operator, check if capture group 1 exists. If it does, return the single word character in group 1 (parameter `g1`) and append the length of the total match (parameter `m`).

If there is no group 1, then 1+ or more whitespace chars are matched due to the alternation `|`, which are replaced with an empty string.

```
(\w)\1+|\s+
```

*Explanation*

- `(\w)\1+` Capture a single word char in **group 1** and repeat that same char 1 or more times which is in backreference `\1`
- `|` Or
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars

```js
const countLetter = s => s
  .replace(/(\w)\1+|\s+/g, (m, g1) => g1 ? g1 + m.length : '')

console.log(countLetter('lorrem ipsssum dollorrrrum'));
```